# For $g(n) = \sum_{d|n}f(d)$, find $g(5000)$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

This is the second part of my previous question asked here. Thanks to your help, I was able to understand why the following function $f(n)$ is multiplicative:

*$f(n)$ is the greatest power of $2$ that divides $n$.*

For example, $f(20) = 2^2 = 4$, $f(32) = 2^5 = 32$, f$(72) = 2^3 = 8$, etc.

I require some help on the next part of the question I'm practicing for my final exam in number theory. The second part is as follows:

*Find $g(5000)$ for $$g(n) = \sum_{d|n}f(d)$$*

From my understanding, as $f(n)$ is multiplicative, $g(n)$ must also be multiplicative, but I'm not sure how to find the actual value of $g(5000)$. I know that $5000 = 2^3 \cdot 5^4$ and so $f(5000) = 2^3 = 8$.

I think I'm a bit confused about the function itself, am I supposed to be summing the divisors of $n = 5000$ or $f(n) = 8$?

I could be completely wrong, so feel free to correct me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint: since $f$ is multiplicative, so is $g$. $g$ is relatively easy to compute at powers of primes.

Comment: Actually $$g(5000)=g(2^3) \cdot g(5^4)= (1+2+4+8)(1+1+1+1+1)= 15 \cdot 5=75$$

Comment: In computing $g(5000)$ the sum is taken over the divisors of $5000$.  As to the problem as a whole, if all else fails you can actually compute the sum term by term.  It's not that bad...there are only $20$ divisors of $5000$.

Comment: Since you know $g(n)$ is multiplicative, it means you either don't understand what multiplicative function is, or you don't understand how to apply it to power of primes, because that is virtually all you need to do then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially @Crostul comment.

You have $g$ is multiplicative ($g=1\ast f$ is the convolution of two multiplicative functions, hence multiplicative)

Multiplicative means that $g(mn)=g(m)g(n)$ when $\gcd(m,n)=1$. In particular a multiplicative function is determined by the values of it in prime powers. So, our question would be what is $g(p^k)$?

If $p=2$: Then $$g(2^k)=\sum_{d|2^k}f(d)=\sum_{0\leq j\leq k}f(2^j)=\sum_{0\leq j\leq k}2^j=2^{k+1}-1$$
If $p\neq 2$: Then $$g(p^k)=\sum_{d|p^k}f(d)=\sum_{0\leq j\leq k}f(p^j)=\sum_{0\leq j\leq k}1=k+1$$

In particular, we have $5000=2^35^4$. Hence,
$$g(5000)=g(2^3)g(5^4)=(2^4-1)(4+1)=(15)(5)=75$$

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an intuitive approach to this problem.

Clearly, 5000 = $2^{3}*5^{4}$ which implies that it has 20 divisors. Out of these 20 divisors, 
5 are of the form $2^{3}*5^{p}$, where $0 <= p <= 4$.
Similarly, 5 are of the form $2^{2}*5^{p}$, where $0 <= p <= 4$ and so on till $ 2^{0}$.

Therefore, $g(n)$ = $\sum_{d|n} f(d)$ = 8x5 + 4x5 + 2x5 + 1x5 = 75.

Edit: I actually misunderstood the question earlier. I added the $k$’s in $2^{k}$ not the $2^{k}$’s.

Answer (score 0):

you have to find the set of $d$ that divide $n$

$5000 = 2^35^4$

factors are $1,5,25,125,625,2,10,50,250,\cdots,8,40,200,1000,5000$

$g(5000) = f(1)+ f(5) + \cdots + f(1000)+ f(5000) = 4(2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3) = 4(2^4-1) = 60$